# VUEjs & vuex with laravel backend authentication/remember

Tags: javascript, laravel, oauth, vue.js, vuex

I'm working on a test-app with vuejs and vuex. I can signup/register the users and
I also got the user logged in and set the token in localstorage vuex. But where and how do you check if the user is already logged in after a refresh?

I'm currently using VUEX to handle async calls with axios.
the structure within my "store" folder is following
 - Index.js
   - actions.js
   - mutations.js
   - getters.js

Here is a part of my actions.js

```
import config from './../config'
import axios from 'axios'
import Ls from '../mixins/localStorage'

axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
};

export default {
    login ({commit,dispatch}, user) {
        commit('setLoading', {
            modalName: 'loginModal',
            state: true
        });
        const endpoint = config.apiUrl + 'clients/web/login';
        axios.post(endpoint, user)
            .then(response => {
                Ls.set('token',response.data.request_key);
                dispatch('getUserData');
                return true;
            })
            .catch(e => {
                commit('setLoading', {
                    modalName: 'loginModal',
                    state: false
                });
                console.log(e);
                return false
            });
    },
    getUserData({commit}){
        const endpoint = config.apiUrl + 'user/profile';
        if(Ls.get('token')) {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + Ls.get('token').replace(/(^\")|(\"$)/g, '');
        }
        axios.get(endpoint)
            .then(response => {
                commit('setUser',response.data);
                commit('hideModal', 'loginModal');
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
                return false
            });
    }
}
```

So the question is

1. is this the right way to log a user in?
2. How and where do you check if the user is already logged in and if so, what do you do next ?

Thanks in advance!